# How to select child tags in imacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

Have one page with links with different IDs, but in parent tag h5:

```
<h5><a id="name_68839764">Some text...</a></h5>
<h5><a id="name_76739765">Other text...</a></h5>
```

How can I click to all of this links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some text...

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H5 ATTR=CLASS:* 
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:*
```

I didn't have too much success with this but it's suppose to work. Try it and let us know.